# Is the way i declared the Abstract-Class wrong/not common?

Tags: c++, abstract-class, c++17

I was told, the way I declared the Abstract-Class is wrong or not used in C++ but it still works.
I couldn't find any useful source to create an opinion about this so I want to know if it's unusual/wrong/right to programm it this way.

```
#pragma once


class TestClass abstract
{

public:

    void test();

    TestClass();
    ~TestClass();
};



int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 

    TestClass baum;
}
```

Error (active) E0322 An object of type "" TestClass "" of an abstract class is not allowed: test

I can't create any object of "TestClass" so my guess is it works but my teacher told me it's wrong.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Is this something from `c++-cli`? That is a different language than standard `c++`.

Comment: I guess it has something to do with Visual C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no explicit keyword to make your class abstract in C++. Your code shouldn't compile because `abstract` isn't a C++ keyword, you're probably using a compiler extension to not have it trip over that keyword.

The way you create an abstract class in C++ is by declaring one or more pure virtual functions, your `test` for example:

```
virtual void test() = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer.